# Setting circular references in one go

Tags: c#

Given the two classes:

```
public class class1
{
  public class2 class2parameter { get; set; }
}

public class class2
{
  public class1 class1parameter { get; set; }
}
```

I can create an instance of class1 like this:

```
  var myclass1 = new class1()
  {
    class2parameter = new class2()
  };
```

But when doing so, is it possible to set the `class1parameter` of the class2 to be equal to the instance of class1 that I am currently creating?

I cannot do this:

```
  var myclass1 = new class1()
  {
    class2parameter = new class2()
    {
      class1parameter = myclass1
    }
  };
```

Because "Cannot use local variable 'myclass1' before it is declared"

Is there any better way than this:

```
  var myclass1 = new class1()
  {
    class2parameter = new class2()
  };
  myclass1.class2parameter.class1parameter = myclass1;
}
```

I would prefer to create and populate class1 and class2 in one single call.

Comment: Personally, when you start mashing too much into a single line, you are making your code unreadable for no real gain. Just stick with what you have at the end of your question. It gets the job done, you can read it, and you have nothing to gain by combining everything to one line.

Comment: There might be ways to achieve this, but why would you want to do this ? Its just poor design.

Comment: As Shekhar says, this is bad design... If you really must go down this line, have a look at "Weak References" - there is a generic weak reference class in .Net you can use...

Answer (score 3):

When you say "one single call" that doesn't really happen under the hood anyway. However, a cleaner way to write it would be:

```
var myclass1 = new Class1();
var myclass2 = new Class2();
myclass1.class2parameter = myclass2;
myclass2.class1parameter = myclass1;
```

In my opinion this is easier to read / understand than lots of embedded statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something this way:

```
  var myclass2 = new class2() { class1parameter = new class1() };
  var myclass1 =  class2.class1parameter;
  class1.class2parameter = class2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you already have is just fine.  You don't need a better way.

If you want to make it look more symmetrical you can so this

```
var myclass1 = new class1();
var myclass2 = new class2();
myclass1.class2parameter = myclass2;
myclass2.class1parameter = myclass1;
```